# How to execute a script by call his id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

from the html below I would like to execute a script by calling his id. So that when the script id is called the display fonction execute. Any other suggestion will be appreciate as long that the script only execute when the id is called. Thank you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
//Here is where I would like to execute the script by calling his id.
//Any other suggestion to make it work will be appreciate
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" id="execute">
$(document).ready(function(){
   display();
});
</script>

<!--------------------- Footer -------------------------------->
<script>
function display(){
 $("#show").css("display", "block");
}
</script>
<p id="show" style="display:none">This is a paragraph with little content.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

That's not how JavaScript works.

Once you include a `<script>` in DOM, **it's executed**. However, the script itself can define functions, which could be named and called at a later point (by their name), by any other script or element in the page, as long as they have access to the context in which you defined your function.

Example:

```html
<script>
  function myFunction() {
    window.alert('I got called!');
  }
</script>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Execute myFunction()</button>
```

So instead of using the `id` of the script, I'm using the name of the function.

---

To fully answer your question: running a script by id is not possible because all scripts are executed as soon as they are parsed by the browser (which happens in their chronological order in DOM) and there is no way of re-running them after they have already been executed.

Obviously, one could argue that you could remove the `<script>` tag altogether, create a new one with the same contents, which ***is*** going to be rerun when added to DOM. But, at least in theory, it's not rerunning the same `<script>`, it's running a different one. Another instance/`<script>` tag.

Needless to say, nobody does that as it's much more convoluted than to simply define a function and call that function at a later time.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your explanation on the DOM. It help me figure out another alternative

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
            var result = window.prompt("Would you like the footer to be display?");
            if(result == "yes"){
            bodyPage1();
            }
            });
        </script>

        <script>
            function bodyPage1(){
                display();
            }
        </script>

        <!--------------------- Footer -------------------------------->
        <script>
            function display(){
                $("#show").css("display", "block");
            }
        </script>
        <p id="show" style="display:none">This is a paragraph with little content.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yep, that works. Note you don't need separate `<script>` tags to define `bodyPage1` (or `display`, for that matter). You can do it all in one tag. Also, `function bodyPage1()(){` should really be `function bodyPage1(){`

Comment: @tao  This is just and example for the project I'm working on. I separate the script tag because I'm working with different files

Comment: The bodyPage function are the different jsp file I will be written the script. I got 3 pages.  bodyPage1, bodyPage2 and bodyPage3 are the pages I would like the footer to be display when the function is called

Comment: I wasn't criticizing. From outside it looks like you're at the start of your journey in web development, so I tried to help, by stating what might not be obvious.

Comment: Thank you for your help. it is much appreciate.